# I need steps and advice on updating a very old instance of Matillion ETL

Tags: amazon-ec2, matillion

I am managing an AWS instance of Matillion ETL for a client. They have no real IT or AWS engineers, and I am not experienced as an AWS admin. Following Matillion instructions, I installed the AMI with version 1.59.8 a few years ago. We have been stable in production during this time with no Matillion version updates since the one in-place update I did in the very beginning.

Although it is a good idea to update to the latest software in general, I have been holding off with Matillion because I do not want to do an "update in-place" which has risks. I am wondering if others have avoided updating the version, or if they have updated - can they provide me some steps on how to safely do this?

**Some background:**
I have only one instance of Matillion. Using the Matillion UI, I scheduled nightly EBS snapshots in AWS. They have been running (and stacking up) all this time. I have never tested a restore, but I can confirm the snapshots are current. I also do full project exports when I perform a release (2x month).

I'd appreciate any instructions on how to test the update of Matillion in a parallel environment.

I have only verified that EBS snapshots are being taken nightly to backup my Matillion AWS instance. I also have used project imports and exports, but never a restore from the EBS snapshots.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options for updating Matillion:
https://documentation.matillion.com/docs/6688312

1. In place updates: just keep running the 'check for updates' and 'update' until you get to current version
2. create a new server instance from marketplace on a new VM and use the migrate function in Matillion to move over current projects and settings.  This is not 100% - not everything gets migrated - see this link for details:
   [Migrate](https://documentation.matillion.com/docs/2966007)

My experience has been that the in place updates work fine.  I have done them many times over 3 years and never had a single issue.

Note also that if you want to upgrade to 1.69 or later, then migrate is the only option.  In place updates will only take you to 1.68.
[1.69 release notes](https://documentation.matillion.com/docs/metl-169-release-notes)